# Regex expression with a word that may appear in a text

Tags: regex, regex-group

I am looking for a Regex expression that may optionally include a word.
Here are some texts that i want my regex expression to find:

- spring-sample-api-123
- spring-sample-api-develop-8g3
- spring-sample-api-83045

And here is one that it should not find:

- spring-sample-api-asda

here is the regex expression that i have so far:

`spring-sample-api-[\bdevelop0-9]+`

but it does not work yet. Can anyone help please?

Comment: You need to remove `\b` and move `[` right after `develop`: `spring-sample-api-develop[0-9]+`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i just checked. that does not work. Some texts have "develop" in them, some not

Comment: I was focused on the typo. To fix the optional part, use `^spring-sample-api(?:-develop)?-[0-9a-zA-Z]*[0-9][0-9a-zA-Z]*$`. Not sure about the last part: what is the rule there? Maybe `^spring-sample-api(?:-develop)?-[0-9].*` will do?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I want this one to be found too: spring-sample-api-develop-86-vnn         The last part can be acombo of letters and numbers

Comment: Yes, see https://regex101.com/r/gy9DPi/2

Answer (score 0):

You can try using

```
^spring-sample-api(?:-develop)?-[0-9].*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gy9DPi/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `spring-sample-api` - a fixed string
- `(?:-develop)?` - an optional group matching `-develop` substring
- `-` - a `-` char
- `[0-9].*` - a digit and then the rest of the line.

Comment: ++This pattern does the trick